# Android Marshmllow Permissions

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have written an android app and in marshmallow devices all permissions are `off` by default like this..
What I want in app permissions

[image]

but I am getting all app permission default off

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html and search first before asking.

Answer (score 2):

> but I am getting all app permission default off

This is perfectly normal, for an app with `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher. Moreover, it is what the *user* wants on Android 6.0: you have no `dangerous` permissions at the outset, and you ask the user for permission if and only if the user does something that requires that permission. Users have complained very loudly over the years that they are tired of apps asking for all sorts of permissions without users having control over those permissions, and you would be wise to respect users in this regard.

Here, by `dangerous`, I am referring to permissions with a [protection level of `dangerous`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel). The documentation outlines [what permissions are `dangerous`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous), though the definitions vary by Android OS version.

You are welcome to set your `targetSdkVersion` to 22 or lower. In that case, your app behaves like out-of-date apps, ones that demand all their `dangerous` permissions at install time. You will wind up with fewer users this way, particularly if you ask for a lot of `dangerous` permissions. And, bear in mind that the user can still toggle off these permissions in Settings on Android 6.0+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

By default all permissions will be off for any app. In `android M` you need to turn it on when required by requesting permissions at runtime [see more](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) depending on what you want like camera, contacts etc